# Azure Network Watcher: Since I already have a Network watcher in my HUB subscription, do I need another Network watcher in the Spoke subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have a HUB Vnet in Hub subscription and Spoke Vnet in Spoke subscription. Both Hub Vnet & Spoke Vnet are in the same region. The HUB subscription have a Network watcher.

Since I already have a Network watcher in my HUB subscription, do I need another Network watcher in the Spoke subscription? Can't I use the Network watcher in my HUB subscription in the Spoke Vnet in the Spoke subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Network watcher will be automatically enabled whenever vnet is created in the subscription

> **Note** **that Network watcher is per subscription, and it is not possible to use hub network watcher by spoke subscription The Network Watcher service is enabled automatically for every subscription.**

Automatically enabling Network Watcher has no negative effects on your resources or costs you anything. Your network troubleshooting will be made simpler and better as a result.

Make sure to include network watcher extension in your virtual machine so you can communicate with it regarding connectivity between two IP addresses this will be very benefits for you like below:

[image]

In your virtual machine -> under setting, Extension ->Add-> Network watcher like below:

[image]

***Reference***:

[Azure Network Watcher | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-monitoring-overview)